# Laravel add dynamic input fields

Tags: php, laravel, bulkinsert, eloquent

I want to insert dynamic fields into DB. I'm using the following code but it does not work as I expect.

```
<html>
<input id="reporting" type="text" value="salman" name="reporting[]">    
<input id="reporting" type="text" value="ankur" name="reporting[]">    
</html>

<?php

 $report = Input::get('reporting');

 for($i=0; $i<=count($report);$i++)
        {
            $news = new Reporting();
            $news->user_id = 1;
            $news->reporting = $report;
            $news->save();
        }
?>
```

expected result:

```
user_id || reporting
1           Salman
1           Ankur
```

Can you guys please help me to fix this.

Comment: What does `dd($report)` show?

Comment: `$news->reporting = $report[$i];`

Comment: dd($report) shows 'salman'

Comment: i insert id number 25 
and when i use this method $news->reporting = $report[$i]; 
it insert 2 rows in db but in first row inserts id number 2 and in second row insert id number 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$report` is an array, current item of it can be received with `[]` notation:

```
$report = Input::get('reporting');

for($i=0; $i<=count($report);$i++)
{
    $news = new Reporting();
    $news->user_id = 1;
    $news->reporting = $report[$i];    // here add [$i]
    $news->save();
}
```

Comment: ya i tried this     $news->reporting = $report[$i];    // here add [$i]
and it inserts 2 rows in db but im using id 25 so it splits the id in both rows, in first it shows id# 2 and in second row id #5

Comment: How do you send your data to server? With ajax or not? If with ajax - show ajax function.

Comment: Very strange then. Assuming your form fields are __correctly named__ `reporting[]`, then `Input::get` __must__ return array, not single field. Try print just `$_POST['reporting']`, if it is not array, then it's not laravel problem.

Comment: i restart the server and than tried again it inserts correct values but shows the error (1/1) ErrorException
Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Remove `=` -> `$i<count($report)`

Answer (score 0):

You could map the collection and create a new report while storing value of reports the way you want:

```
<html>
<body>
@if(session('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('success') }}
</div>
@endif
<form action="/" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input id="reporting" type="text" value="salman" name="reporting[]">    
  <input id="reporting" type="text" value="ankur" name="reporting[]">  
  <button type ="submit"> Send </button>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Catch data on backend:

```
public function store()
{
    $fields = collect(Input::get('reporting'));

    $fields->map(function($value, $key){

        return Reporting::create([

            'user_id'=>1,

            'reporting'=>$value,
        ]);

    });

   return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Action was successful');
}
```

This will produce the data in this format:

```
user_id || reporting
1           Salman
1           Ankur
```

Note: Tested working correctly!

Comment: Error: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Collection {#217 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => "multiple"
  ]
}

Comment: I think your html its different from what you are displaying in the question. Try using my way it will work 100%.