# How to add multiply input fields and parse that data to the database

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

[image]

So I have this form above this works correctly with the following code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">{{ __('borrow book') }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('Borrowed.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="serialnumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('please scan serialnumber') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required autofocus>
                    @if ($errors->has('serialnumber'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('serialnumber') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="ma_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('please scan your member card') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!--<input id="ma_id" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('ma_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('ma_id') }}" required> -->
                    <input id="ma_id" type="password" class="form-control" name="ma_id" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('ma_id'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('ma_id') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('send') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller to get the Data to the database:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    request()->validate([
        'serialnumber' => 'required',
        'ma_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    Ausleih::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('borrowed.index');
}
```

I have tested the following samples :

1. [laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jqueryexample.html](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jqueryexample.html)
2. [laravel-add-dynamic-input-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496851/laravel-add-dynamic-input-fields)
3. [laravel/dynamically-add-input-fields-and-save-to-database](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamically-add-input-fields-and-save-to-database?page=1)

I read these as well

1. [laravel.com/docs/4.2/html](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)
2. [learninglaravel.net/dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jquery-in-laravel-55](https://learninglaravel.net/dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jquery-in-laravel-55)

I just want to make it possible for members to offer the chance to borrow more than one book without having to go through this window again and again if they want to borrow 5 books directly.

Would any of you have a solution for my problem or could you refer to something helpful that would allow me to solve the described problem? I am very grateful for any help and would like to thank you in advance for your efforts. I would also like to say that I am not an expert in Laravel so I would politely ask you to describe your answer understandable for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

No need to dynamically add input fields.
I assume you are using a barcode scanner. So you should automatically format barcodes so they all fit in one input field.

For example, you could automatically add a semi-colon to each scanned barcode:
1ABCDEF;2ABCDEF;3ABCDEF;etc...

And, in your controller, you just need to get all the books' barcodes with: `explode(";", $serialnumber);`

Comment: I dont like the idea to scan them all in one input field. When you want to look up the books you scanned its hard to check them all when you have this little view of one input field. But thanks for the suggestion!